# Archiving Files

Tags: file-management

I really like the way gmail has the archive system implemented. I can archive any file after adding a tag to it (if needed) and I can search for it whenever I want to.
Is there any program in Windows/Linux which behaves in a similar fashion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you "Archive" in gmail you are just removing a hidden tag ("INBOX").
It does not seem a useful thing to do in your own file system, since you are not actually "archiving" anything.
Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at http://code.google.com/p/xtagfs/, (or generally search for something like "tag-based filesystem"; there are likely more).  This allows you to tag files, and later get a listing of all files with a particular tag/tags (and it "feels" just like a normal filesystem).  Seems quite like what you are looking for, with a bit of tweaking perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

You might like google's GoogleDesktop... it doesn't have tagging per-se, but it seems to have pretty effective desktop search.